# selecting rows in a tuplelist in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I have a list of tuples as below in python:

```
   Index        Value
     0         (1,2,3)
     1         (2,5,4)
     2         (3,3,3)
```

How can I select rows from this in which the second value is less than or equal 2?

***EDIT:***

Basically, the data is in the form of `[(1,2,3), (2,5,4), (3,3,3)....]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the `tuple` by using `apply`:

```
df[df['Value'].apply(lambda x: x[1] <= 2)]
```

[image]

---

Seems, it was a list of tuples and not a `DF`:

To return a `list` back:

```
data = [item for item in [(1,2,3), (2,5,4), (3,3,3)] if item[1] <= 2]
# [(1, 2, 3)]
```

To return a `series` instead:

```
pd.Series(data)
#0    (1, 2, 3)
#dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Comment: Can you show me the way in which the dataframe is constructed by editing the post?

Comment: I haven't changed my tuplelist to dataframe. I thought that I could select rows from the tuplelist directly.

Comment: You mean, you have `[(1,2,3), (2,5,4), (3,3,3)]` currently?

Comment: Yes, this is what I have.

Comment: Try this: `pd.Series([item for item in tuple_list if item[1] <= 2])` where `tuple_list`: list of tuples you have. This returns a series. If you do not want a series, but a list as o/p, just omit `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df["Value"].str[1] <= 2]
```

You can read this for more details - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str

Comment: I got this error: "'list' object has no attribute 'Value'".

Comment: Try this or put the name of the column if it's different than "Value".

Comment: It's a list and I haven't changed it to dataframe.

Comment: Okay. Convert your list to a dataframe first - ```df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": your-list})```

Answer (score 0):

just to put this out there.  you should read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  your question was/is confusing because it looks as though you've got 2 good answers and your not satisfied.  then you edited your question to be clearer, but just barely.

ok, now that i've got my editorial out of the way.

---

***setup***
this is what i'm assuming i'm working with

```
# list of tuples
lot = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 4), (3, 3, 3)]
```

***desired output***
i think.  btw, nothing to do with pandas at all

```
[(a, b, c) for a, b, c in lot if b <= 2]

[(1, 2, 3)]
```

***with pandas***
however, since you did tag this pandas

```
s = pd.Series(lot)
```

@TrigonaMinima's answer, give them credit if this works for you.

```
s[s.str[1].le(2)]

0    (1, 2, 3)
dtype: object
```